# Same observations on data frame feature appear as independent

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have got the following DF:

`carrier_name   sol_carrier
aapt            702
aapt carrier    185
afrix           72
afr-ix          4
airtel          35
airtel          2
airtel dia and broadband    32
airtel mpls standard circuits   32
amt             6
anca test       1
appt            1
at tokyo        1
at&t            5041
att             2
batelco         723
batelco         2
batelco (manual) 4
beeline         1702
beeline - 01    6
beeline - 02    6`

i need to get a unique list of `carrier_name` so I have done some basic housekeeping as I only want to keep the names with no white spaces at the beginign or end of the observation with the following code:

```
`carrier = pd.DataFrame(data['sol_carrier'].value_counts(dropna=False))
carrier['carrier_name'] = carrier.index
carrier['carrier_name'] = carrier['carrier_name'].str.strip()
carrier['carrier_name'] = carrier['carrier_name'].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')
carrier['carrier_name'] = np.where(carrier['carrier_name']==' ',np.NaN,carrier['carrier_name'])
carrier['carrier_name'] = carrier['carrier_name'].str.strip()
carrier = carrier.reset_index(drop=True)
carrier = carrier[['carrier_name','sol_carrier']]
carrier.sort_values(by='carrier_name')`
```

what happens here is that i get a list of `carrier_name` but still get some duplicate observations like `airtel` or `beeline`for example. I dont understand why this is happening as both observations are the same and and there are no more whitespaces at the begining or the end of the observation and, this observations are followed by its respective `value_counts()`so there is no reason for them to be duplicated. Here is the same DF but after the above code has been applied:

`carrier_name   sol_carrier
aapt            702
aapt carrier    185
afr ix          4
afrix           72
airtel          35
airtel          2
airtel dia and broadband    32
airtel mpls standard circuits   32
amt             6
anca test       1
appt            1
at t            5041
at tokyo        1
att             2
batelco         723
batelco         2
batelco  manual 4
beeline         1702
beeline         6
beeline         6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you don't aggregate the results you just change the values in 'carrier_name' columns.

To aggregate the results call

```
carrier.groupby('carrier_name').sol_carrier.sum()
```

or modify the 'data' dataframe and then call

```
data['sol_carrier'].value_counts()
```